# Image verification code problem

Tags: php, html, ajax, verification, contact-form

Hey all, I've added an image verification code to my contact form. It successfully displays the image but it tells me that the image verification code is wrong even if i type it in right. I believe it's a problem in my contactform.php

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
<label>Name:*</label><INPUT class="textbox" type="text" name="name" value=""><br />

<label>E-Mail:*</label><INPUT class="textbox" type="text" name="email" value=""><br />

<label>Telephone:</label><INPUT class="textbox" type="text" name="Telephone" value=""      /><br />

<INPUT class="textbox" type="hidden" name="subject" value="Contact Form" >

<label>Message:*</label><TEXTAREA class="textbox" NAME="message" ROWS="5" COLS="25">    </TEXTAREA><br />
<tr>
<label>Image  Verification:*</label>
        <input type="text"  name="verify" style="width:200px;" /><img  src="verification.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="Help us  avoid spam! Please type the image text in the box" width="50"  height="24" align="absbottom" />


<label>&nbsp;</label><INPUT class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

Here is the contactform.php that it sends to:

```
<?php
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
*/

include 'config.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
include 'functions.php';

$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$telephone = stripslashes($_POST['telephone']);
$subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
$verify = stripslashes($_POST['verify']);


$error = '';

// Check name

if(!$name)
{
$error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
}

// Check email

if(!$email)
{
$error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
}

if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
{
$error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
}

// Check message (length)

if(!$message || strlen($message) < 15)
{
$error .= "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.<br />";
}

// Check Verification code
if(md5($verify).'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' !=  $_cookie['contact_verify'])
{
$error .= "Image Verification failed.<br />";
}





//Send the Name, Email, Telephone, and Message in a formated version.
$email_message = "The following message was sent to you in your contact form on domain.com\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $email_message,
 "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
}

}
?>
```

And finally.. here is verification.php that generates the verification image:

```
<?php

//Declare in the header what kind of file this is
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

//A nice small image that's to the point 
$width = 50;
$height = 24;

//Here we create the image with the sizes declared above and save it to a  variable my_image
$my_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

//Let's give our image a background color.  White sound ok to everyone?
imagefill($my_image, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

//Now we're going to add some noise to the image by placing pixels  randomly all over the image
for ($c = 0; $c < 40; $c++){
$x = rand(0,$width-1);
$y = rand(0,$height-1);
imagesetpixel($my_image, $x, $y, 0x000000);
}

$x = rand(1,10);
$y = rand(1,10);

$rand_string = rand(1000,9999);
imagestring($my_image, 5, $x, $y, $rand_string, 0x000000);

/*
We're going to store a ****** in the user's browser so we can call to it
later and confirm they entered the correct verification. The
"md5 rand string" can be anything you want.  It's just our personal
code to be added to the end of the captcha value stored in the ******
as an encrypted string
*/
setcookie('contact_verify',(md5($rand_string).'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'));

imagejpeg($my_image);
imagedestroy($my_image);
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: php variables are case-sensitive. it's not $_cookie. Write all your code under `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to avoid such a silly mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't transmit cookies until the page refreshes. So when you submit your form through AJAX, it's not getting the cookie. A better way to do this would be to store the image verification code in a $_SESSION variable, rather than in a cookie:

```
$_SESSION['contact_verify'] = (md5($rand_string).'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6');
```

Comment: what's the difference? Why $_SESSION variable would succeed over cookie?

Comment: Because $_SESSION is stored server side, immediately when it's set. Cookies must be sent to the browser and then retransmitted on the next request. Why don't you try it out first?

Comment: LOL. Why don't you try it out first? Well, the value was stored on the server side, all right. Now we want to associate incoming request with stored value, do we?

Comment: I'm sorry.. this is one of my first times using PHP. Ive set the $_cookie in my contactform.php to $_session. 

But in my verification.php I'm not sure what to change "setcookie" to. because I dont believe there is a "setsession"

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Regardless of whether this would solve the problem described in the question, it's still a terrible idea to do verification based solely on stuff the user is giving you, and the asker should still be using session variables rather than cookies.

Comment: @MJ93 Use $_SESSION['contact_verify'] = {cookie_value}. I updated my post to show an example.

Comment: @Anon. You are wrong. The OP's scheme is unbreakable. Nothing terrible here.

Comment: @MJ93 don't bee a fool. Don't alter your code mindlessly. Don't listen to ones who either don't understand. Try to understand what are you doing! And then repair mistakes. That's the only way! Doing just copy/paste without understanding will lead you straight to hell.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Sorry, I must have missed the memo about md5 being suddenly immune to rainbow-tabling.

Comment: @Anon ROTFLMAO. Oh, yes, someone would bother with table lookups to break a captcha. I'd wish some scum would do it. It will occupy their servers, letting less resources to actual spam

Comment: @mdarwi Anyways.. Thanks for the update mdarwi, however the error saying that the Image Verification failed is still showing up :/
I'm almost positive its an error in my // Check Verification Code
statement. If I change:
if(md5($verify).'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' !=  $_SESSION['contact_verify'])

to

if(md5($verify).'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' ==  $_SESSION['contact_verify'])

then it sends the email but it doesnt matter whether you enter the correct verification number or not.
So I'm not sure where to go from here..